# display paragraph django form widget

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms, widget

I am new to django

I have a Author admin form which contains Inlines of several related forms
While Editing any author form i want to display a readonly element of associated books with it in a inline like way.
I cant find a way to fetch all the related objects and show a markup object.
(Book have a many to many relation ship with author)
Instead i have used a Multi model choice field

```
class AuthorForm(FormCleanMixin):
       assoc_books = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Books.objects.none(),required=False)

class AuthorAdmin():
     def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
     if obj is not None:
        form.base_fields['assoc_books'].queryset = Books.objects.filter(authors=obj.id)
    else:
        form.base_fields.pop('assoc_books')
```

i am getting the output in a select box. Is there a way to convert it into a paragraph where i can also insert some HTML to it.I want to list each book to its own url. /admin/book//change

I have tried this but the anchor tag doesnt display

```
class listRelatedItemsField(forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        html = '''<a target='_blank' href='admin/book/%(id)s/change'>%(name)s</a>''' % {'id':obj.id,'name':obj.name}
    return mark_safe(html)
```

Can i create a custom widget for this.
Please help